# EventHandlerList does not exist on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

i bumped into issue when I wanted to use EventHandlerList in Windows Phone application. Errro occured telling me it was not found even though msdn claims it is supposed to exist on WP platform. http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.componentmodel.eventhandlerlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Do you happen to know what I;m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided does not mention support of Windows Phone anywhere in the documentation.

Please be aware that Windows Phone 8 uses a subset of the .NET 4.5 framework, so not everything is present.

Comment: In paragraph Platforms WP is mentioned.

Comment: Ah, I see confusion - it's not mentioned in the English version of docs - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.eventhandlerlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - I guess it hasn't been translated across correctly?!